# How are we supposed to use different google fonts?

Tags: css

I try to add some fonts to my website e.g. Montserrat. So I selected them [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Montserrat:wght@500;800#standard-styles).

I selected **Medium 500** and **Extra-bold 800**. It provided me this `link`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

File:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

I don't understand how I can use the two fonts, what do I have to specify for font-family?

```css
.extra-bold {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-ExtraBold';
}
.medium {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="extra-bold">This text should be Montserrat extra bold</p>
<p class="medium">This text should be Medium 500</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font family is just "Montserrat". You need to specify a font weight to get the bold/medium styles.

```css
.extra-bold {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 800;
}
.medium {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="extra-bold">This text should be Montserrat extra bold</p>
<p class="medium">This text should be Medium 500</p>
```

If you look in the `@font-face` declarations, you'll see this (abbreviated):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
```

The `font-family` is the same, but the `font-weight` is set depending on the font that is being referenced. If you look at the `src` parameter, you'll notice a different font file is being called depending on the weight.

Comment: Then why do I need to select multiple fonts on their site if I really need just one?

Comment: Because you need to include the actual font file for the bold vs medium

Comment: You don't need only one, you said that you need 2 of them. If you only chose one, you wouldn't get font-faces for a font with other weight.